# Java can not connect with database

Tags: java, database, eclipse, workbench

Everyone! I am doing a project(Java Eclipse) that need to connect with a database(MySQL workbench).
But I am facing a problem which is the login page. I have already built an account and password database, and I use JFrame to connect with that database to use in the login page. I built student_ID = 'S0761129' and student_Password = 'S0761129' in database. However, I enter the same thing in JFrame. But the system show "Incorrect Account and Password". Actually, I have already surfed the Internet and followed the steps. Unfortunately, I cannot run the program. Hope everyone gives some constructive suggestions to me. Here is the whole code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class LoginPage extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField account;
    private JTextField password;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoginPage frame = new LoginPage();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public LoginPage() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 297, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblId = new JLabel("ID");
        lblId.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblId.setBounds(41, 84, 49, 37);
        contentPane.add(lblId);

        account = new JTextField();
        account.setBounds(101, 92, 121, 21);
        contentPane.add(account);
        account.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblPassword.setBounds(26, 134, 136, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblPassword);

        password = new JTextField();
        password.setBounds(99, 137, 120, 21);
        contentPane.add(password);
        password.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblLoginSystem = new JLabel("Login System");
        lblLoginSystem.setFont(new Font("標楷體", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        lblLoginSystem.setBounds(56, 22, 239, 52);
        contentPane.add(lblLoginSystem);

        JButton Login = new JButton("Login");


        Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_project", "root", "");
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    String sql = "Select * from student_info where ID = 0 and Student_ID='" + account.getText() + "' and Student_Password = '" + password.toString() + "'";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (rs.next())
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Sucessfully...");
                    else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Account and Password...");
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print(e);
                }
            }
        });
        Login.setBounds(56, 190, 76, 23);
        contentPane.add(Login);

        JButton Reset = new JButton("Reset");
        Reset.setBounds(142, 190, 86, 23);
        contentPane.add(Reset);
    }
}
```

Comment: That fact that you are getting *Incorrect Account and Password* means that you are connecting to the DB, but not fetching a record.  Are you sure that the ID **is** `0` ?

Comment: Assuming you don't get any exception which you didn't tell us about your "cannot connect with database" is wrong. It looks like you're successfully connecting but your query returns no results. That might be because of the query (e.g. is that `where ID = 0` correct?) or the data you've entered. - One other important thing: _do not_ append parameter values directly to a query string as that makes the query vulnerable to injection. Use `PreparedStatement` and proper parameter placeholders instead.

Comment: You are also wide open to SQL Injection attacks. Don't concatenate SQL queries like that - use PreparedStatement.

Comment: Thank you guys~ I have already found out the problem and solved it. The problem is in database, I choose the wrong data type.